# Unable to click a visible search button with python-selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nosuchelementexception

I'm not able to click a visible search button with python-selenium as the web-driver cannot find the element.
The selenium web-driver cannot find the search button on the [Kayak.com](https://www.Kayak.com) website. The button is visible but web-driver cannot find it:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

I have tried XPath, full XPath, CSS. Has anyone faced a similar problem in their project and how did you manage to click the button?

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried till now ? And where you are getting error.

Comment: webdriver cannot find it: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. Then I tried css as '.icon > .\_ivP' and it worked.

Comment: Glad you found out solution.  Just a suggestion , next time please share code written by you, so that other can help you more accurately. Also i am guessing your locator was wrong/ or page was not loading properly before it can click search icon. Tries with this code with xpath and it works: 
search = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='icon ']")))
search.click()

Comment: can you share your code segment here so we can clarify and give solution ?

Comment: <span class="icon "> 
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="_ivP _iv1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 54 54" width="54" height="54"><path fill="currentColor" d="M38.25,35.59l-4.42-4.41a10.14,10.14,0,1,0-3.65,3.65l4.41,4.42a2.59,2.59,0,0,0,3.66-3.66ZM17.53,26.1a7.58,7.58,0,1,1,7.58,7.58A7.59,7.59,0,0,1,17.53,26.1Z"></path></svg>
</span>